# How to normalise unique dates for graphing

Tags: python

I've currently got a data-set from an application, but the problem is the data is listed whenever it changes, not on a regular interval. For example I could have 20 entries in one day and then nothing for two days, then one, then one next month.

I want to graph the data I have, but with a consistent time scale - currently it just graphs every entry with every date one after the other.

I have thought about the problem and an idea that came to mind would be determining the start and end date of the data, dividing it by the graphing resolution desired, (eg 100 entries), then for each entry working out the closest result in the data-set BEFORE the resolution sample. ie one of the samples for graphing is 10th of january, it finds the first sample before the 10th of january and uses it. Then with 100 samples you can graph with a consistent time scale.

Any ideas on how to actually achieve this would be wonderful! I'm looking to normalize in python and then render in a browser with google chart api.

Here is an example of the data:

```
10/03/2015 10:55    7385498415
10/03/2015 9:15     7379639094
10/03/2015 8:55     7376777516
10/03/2015 8:35     7368304217
10/03/2015 8:12     7358015859
8/03/2015 9:22      7358015859
8/03/2015 4:27      7354221274
8/03/2015 4:07      7346810719
7/03/2015 4:25      7339695326
7/03/2015 4:25      7339698276
6/03/2015 13:08     7339701226
6/03/2015 13:04     7317905872
6/03/2015 12:44     7309771372
6/03/2015 12:24     7300851599
6/03/2015 12:04     7292557469
6/03/2015 11:39     7283439433
6/03/2015 11:00     7278056128
6/03/2015 10:41     7267320628
6/03/2015 10:35     7265158228
6/03/2015 10:21     7265158228
6/03/2015 10:01     7255260402
6/03/2015 7:06      7246047762
5/03/2015 15:39     7245760885
5/03/2015 13:41     7170760885
4/03/2015 21:21     5595760885
4/03/2015 18:59     5590496476
4/03/2015 18:59     5585251201
```

Comment: Sounds like you are over-complicating things. A chart with proper time support would not have equidistant data points on the X axis, but space them according to when actually happened. Solve that problem instead -- if Google charts don't support time-series data properly (which would be rather surprising), switch to something else.

Comment: Pandas is the solution here: You can lift the code pretty much verbatim from this blog post by Wes McKinney, Pandas' creator. http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need to “normalise” the data, as the Google Charts API has support for dates directly. Not only is adjusting the data more difficult, but it will also give a skewed impression.

We can start with the [Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes) section of their documentation:

> To create a new `Date` object, you call the `Date()` constructor with the new keyword, with arguments to specify components of the date. These arguments take the form of several numbers corresponding to the different properties of your date.
>
> ```
> new Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)
> ```

A row in a Google Chart is an `[x, y]` list. The first entry will be one of these Date() constructors, and the second will be the value. So we need to take the data you’ve provided, parse the dates and turn them into Date() constructors. (Note that we can omit the second and millisecond arguments.)

Here’s a simple script that does this, and then wraps each time in a row that we can supply to a Google Chart:

```
from datetime import datetime

# This string is a copy of the example data set. The newlines have been
# replaced with '\n' escape codes to save vertical space on Stack Overflow.
DATASET = """10/03/2015 10:55    7385498415\n10/03/2015 9:15     7379639094\n10/03/2015 8:55     7376777516\n10/03/2015 8:35     7368304217\n10/03/2015 8:12     7358015859\n8/03/2015 9:22      7358015859\n8/03/2015 4:27      7354221274\n8/03/2015 4:07      7346810719\n7/03/2015 4:25      7339695326\n7/03/2015 4:25      7339698276\n6/03/2015 13:08     7339701226\n6/03/2015 13:04     7317905872\n6/03/2015 12:44     7309771372\n6/03/2015 12:24     7300851599\n6/03/2015 12:04     7292557469\n6/03/2015 11:39     7283439433\n6/03/2015 11:00     7278056128\n6/03/2015 10:41     7267320628\n6/03/2015 10:35     7265158228\n6/03/2015 10:21     7265158228\n6/03/2015 10:01     7255260402\n6/03/2015 7:06      7246047762\n5/03/2015 15:39     7245760885\n5/03/2015 13:41     7170760885\n4/03/2015 21:21     5595760885\n4/03/2015 18:59     5590496476\n4/03/2015 18:59     5585251201"""

# For each line in the dataset, print the row which will be added to the
# Google Chart.
for line in DATASET.splitlines():
    date, value = line.split("    ")

    # First we parse the date string using strptime(), and write it back out
    # as a Date() constructor to use in JavaScript
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    js_date = date_obj.strftime("new Date(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %s, %f)")

    js_value = value.strip()

    print "[%s, %s]," % (js_date, js_value)
```

Here’s a few rows of the output:

```
[new Date(2015, 03, 10, 10, 55, 1425984900, 000000), 7385498415],
[new Date(2015, 03, 10, 09, 15, 1425978900, 000000), 7379639094],
[new Date(2015, 03, 10, 08, 55, 1425977700, 000000), 7376777516],
[new Date(2015, 03, 10, 08, 35, 1425976500, 000000), 7368304217],
```

Then I took the [scatter plot example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart) from Google’s Chart gallery, dropped in the date values I got from the script above, and changed a few of the options. This is what it looks like:

[image]

and here’s the HTML:

```html
<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Value'],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 10, 10, 55), 7385498415],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 10, 09, 15), 7379639094],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 10, 08, 55), 7376777516],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 10, 08, 35), 7368304217],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 10, 08, 12), 7358015859],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 08, 09, 22), 7358015859],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 08, 04, 27), 7354221274],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 08, 04, 07), 7346810719],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 07, 04, 25), 7339695326],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 07, 04, 25), 7339698276],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 13, 08), 7339701226],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 13, 04), 7317905872],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 12, 44), 7309771372],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 12, 24), 7300851599],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 12, 04), 7292557469],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 11, 39), 7283439433],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 11, 00), 7278056128],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 10, 41), 7267320628],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 10, 35), 7265158228],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 10, 21), 7265158228],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 10, 01), 7255260402],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 06, 07, 06), 7246047762],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 05, 15, 39), 7245760885],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 05, 13, 41), 7170760885],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 04, 21, 21), 5595760885],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 04, 18, 59), 5590496476],
        [new Date(2015, 03, 04, 18, 59), 5585251201]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Variable'},
        legend: 'none',
        height: 500,
        width: 1100
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chart_div"></div>

</body>
```